# Deactivate an element via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a DOM element (child of the element to which I have assigned my controller) and I want, upon adding the class "ianctive" (which makes the element look inactive - by graying it out), to disable ALL the AngularJS interactions in that element (in this case, ng-click and all inputs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a model property to keep track of enable/disable state, then add ng-disable directive to all of the form elements.  For ng-click, modify the expressions to also look at this new model property to determine if they should do anything.

E.g., if your new model property is $scope.inactive:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="inactive" ng-model="...">
<a ng-click="inactive || (prop1=prop1 + 1)">click to increase</a> {{prop1}}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/sT6yk/)

Comment: "inactive || " was really the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks!